# Gambeling question

Tags: probability, distributions, games

I am organizing a card game and I need to preset my cards so that if a player draws 26 out of 52 cards randomly, chance for him to pick 4 queens in that draw is the least probable. What is the best way to preset the deck of cards to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Replace the queens by non-queens.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'randomly'? I'd normally interpret the intent in a question like this to indicate a drawing scheme where all (~496 trillion) possible sets of 26 cards drawn from 52 would be equally likely, in which case there's no arrangement of four queens in the deck that can possibly make any difference at all since each such queens arrangement has the same chance of getting 4 queens in 26 randomly chosen cards (which I believe is the underlying serious point of whuber's seemingly facetious comment).

Comment: Consider that randomly (in the common sense) drawing 26 cards is equivalent to completely shuffling your careful arrangement before drawing 26 cards. If you mean something else (e.g. randomly *cutting* the deck and then taking 26 cards in order), then you need to be completely explicit. (In that particular case of a random *cut* of a pre-arranged deck your task is trivial - you can easily set it up so that no consecutive set of 26 cards in your sequence can have 4 queens in it)